# How to add changes when using git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a question about git.I'm working in a project and i have 9 branches, the first branch name was `make users system`.

Today i want to add an avatar to my users but i don't know what is the step to do with git.

Should i create a **new branch** ?

```
git checkout -b add-more-details-to-users
```

Or just **switch** to my **first** branch `make users system` then add changes ?

thank for helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your workflow. If you're working in a team, most of the times when implementing a new feature it's better to create a new branch, test it and merge with the master. It's not a good practice to put too much code and implemented features in one branch since it increases the possibility of breaking up some other functionality.

Also I would suggest you to make your branch names more descriptive, like: add-avatar-to-user , not make-users-system and if you're using any project management tools, task/story id like so: add-avatar-to-user-12345

Take a look at this link, I like this kind of workflow, we are currently using it in our team:
http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like `make users system` is like your master branch, you should checkout a new branch from it, which is called a feature branch, add the changes and, when you're happy the changes and everything works, merge it back.

You should really read up on some articles on how to keep your branches organized
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/